# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table magento

Tags: magento-1.7

When I try to create an `admin_user` table on the server I get this error:

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
```

The DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin_user` (
  `user_id` mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastname` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `username` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `logdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `lognum` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reload_acl_flag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `extra` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_ADMIN_USER_USERNAME` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What is wrong?